# SwiperJS auto slidesPerView does not work with angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, swiper.js

I use `Swiper` with `angular 5` , but if I set `slidesPerView: 'auto'`, the slides not work(cannot see all sliders), event i have set the `loopedSlides`. After checking the css code generated, i found that the swiper-wrapper is with the wrong `translate3d(1024px, 0px, 0px)`, and i cannot see the sliders.
**But if i resize the window, the sliders show!**
May I know why this happen?
Pls help to resolve this poblem, thanks a lot!

sources codes:

> App.component.ts

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import Swiper from 'swiper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  silderVm: Swiper;
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.silderVm = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      loop: true,
      loopedSlides: 2,
      centeredSlides: true,
      spaceBetween: 60,
      slidesPerView: 'auto'
    })
  }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

> app.component.css

```
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and after a couple of days of research, since I know the slide element width and it is constant, I added the breakpoints:

```
breakpoints: {
  1500: {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 15,
  },
  1000: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 15,
  },
  500: {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 0,
  }
}
```

I hope this **workaround** will help you!

Comment: It works if not use auto slidesPerView, but with number; but we need to use auto slidesPerView; the sliders show if I init swiper in ngOnInit lifehook, and update swiper in ngAfterViewInit lifehook, but still have other bugs

Answer (score 0):

Using ngx-swiper-wrapper helped me. It works with slidesPerView: ‘auto’